# DAX PowerBI - Dynamic measure based on data type

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data dump from our financial system, containing Department, GLCode, Year, Month, and Ledger (being Actual $ or Actual FTE) and the amount.

I want to display in a matrix, showing the sum of Actual $ the Actual FTE, BUT, when I drill up on the matrix to just the year, it SUMS the FTE (which is wrong).

I've managed to create a measure which averages the FTE and then multiplies it up by a distinct row count to get a result (you may notice I'm a bit lost).  But that maths then breaks the $$ amount, and I don't know how to calculate a measure for the FTE one way, and the measure for the $$'s another way, but return them in the same variable!!

Sorry if confusing.

```
Department            GLCode         Ledger       Year      Month      Value
02.Provider Service   3000.222.101   Actual $     2016/17   01-Jul   1269.69
02.Provider Service   3000.222.101   Actual $     2016/17   02-Aug   1461.94
02.Provider Service   3000.222.101   Actual FTE   2016/17   01-Jul      0.25
02.Provider Service   3000.222.101   Actual FTE   2016/17   02-Aug      0.27
```

The above needs to return $2731.63 for Actual $ and 0.26 for Actual FTE

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to pivot your data on `Ledger` column to get separate `Value` columns for `Actual $` and `Actual FTE`. Click `Edit queries`, select `Ledger` column and click `Transform` -> `Pivot Column` selecting `Value` for values column:

[image]

Then set the default summarization of `Actual FTE` to be `Average`:

[image]

Then you can add these columns to your visuals and have different summarizations - sum on `Actual $` and average on `Actual FTE`, e.g. like this:

[image]

Comment: Aha - thanks for that.  That is somewhat helpful, but it seems I oversimplified my data example.  Where I have the GLCode currently, is actually part of a larger heirarchy.  My dates go along the top of the matrix, and the GL heirarchy down the left.

Comment: I managed to figure this out by averaging the FTE and them multiplying by the distinct number of GL codes in the hierarchy (which turns the average back into the sum).  This works, but it's a MEASURE which is calculated dynamically. 
I'm sure it must be simple, but I want to show this measure alongside the sum of $.